# languageext Either.Map/Bind with a Task in the Right position

Tags: c#, functional-programming, async-await

I am using the toolkit [languageext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) package for C# and am running into a problem with the Either class when the Right value is some kind of Task.  For some reason this is causing a hang:

```
        var res = repo.GetAccountWithID(accountID)
            .Map(c => filesServiceCustomer.Initialize(c))
            .Bind(t => t.Result);
```

Here, `GetAccountWithID` returns an `Either<Exception, Account>` and the `Initialize` method take an `Account` and returns a `Task<Either<Exception, bool>>`.  However, it would appear that either the `Map` or `Bind` calls are hanging.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm the author of the language-ext project).  There's no fundamental reason for your expression to hang, other than if the `Task` itself is blocking - `Map` and `Bind` are trivial functions that don't do anything particularly clever, and definitely don't do any synchronisation or anything like that.  I just added this code to the unit tests in lang-ext, and it returns fine:

```
    public class Account : NewType<Account, Unit>
    {
        public Account(Unit _) : base(unit) { }
    }

    Either<Exception, Account> GetAccountWithID(int accountId) =>
        Account.New(unit);

    Task<Either<Exception, bool>> Initialize(Account c) =>
        Task.FromResult(Right<Exception, bool>(true));

    [Fact]
    public void StackOverflowQuestion()
    {
        int accountID = 0;

        var res = GetAccountWithID(accountID)
            .Map(c => Initialize(c))
            .Bind(t => t.Result);
    }
```

One thing it's worth mentioning is that it's not great practice to call `.Result` on a task.  You can definitely leverage other features in language-ext to make this work better for you:

For example:

```
    var task = from c in GetAccountWithID(accountID).AsTask()
               from r in Initialize(c)
               select r;
```

`AsTask` lifts the `Either<Exception, Account>` into a `Task<Either<Exception, Account>>`, which then means it's usable in a LINQ expression with `Initialize` (which also returns a `Task`).

If you're fundamentally opposed to the LINQ syntax, then you can do:

```
    var task = GetAccountWithID(accountID).AsTask().BindT(Initialize);
```

`task` is then a `Task<Either<Exception, bool>>` which you can `await`:

```
    var res = (await task).IfLeft(false);
```

Another trick (if you're using version `2.0.*`) is to use `Sequence` which flips the inner and outer monads:

```
    var res = task.Sequence();
```

That will turn the `Task<Either<Exception, bool>>` into a `Either<Exception, Task<bool>>` which you can match on.  Obviously it depends on your use-case as to what's most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, @louthster.  I will look into this.  I'm not opposed to LINQ syntax (I use it elsewhere), I'm just more used to the bind/map idioms.  I will check but I think I am currently using the last of the 1.x versions as they were the stable versions available on Nuget.

Comment: I'm still coming up to speed on the details of the async/await infrastructure.  I wasn't aware of the AsTask() extension.  And I didn't realize that this could then be used the way you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, your environment has a synchronization context and calling `Result` or `Wait` will almost always deadlock.

I don't know what that library does, but this will probably work:

```
var res = (await repo.GetAccountWithID(accountID)
    .Map(c => filesServiceCustomer.Initialize(c)))
    .Bind(t => t);
```

Comment: Thanks, @paulo-morgado,  I actually tried that but it didn't seem to work either.  See my expanded 'answer' I just posted for more context.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context here on what I found and what is happening.  I managed to 'fix' the problem though I am not sure exactly what was causing it or why the fix is needed.

First of all this is running in an Azure API app service.  Not sure if that makes a difference or not but it is included for completeness.

Inside the `Initialize` function there were two lines at the end that look like this:

```
rootDir = someShare.GetRoodDirectoryReference();
...
dir1 = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(dir1Name);
await dir1.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

dir2 = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(dir2Name);
await dir2.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

The code was hanging on the `await` of the first `CreateIfNotExistAsync()` call (whichever was in that position, it didn't matter).  However, I changed this to:

```
dir1 = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(dir1Name);
dir2 = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(dir2Name);

Task<bool> tasks = {
    Task.Run(dir1.CreateIfNotExistAsync),
    Task.Run(dir2.CreateIfNotExistAsync),
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

And, like magic, no more hang!

Now my calling code works as expected.  I don't know why this fix is needed.  The only thing I can think of is that the continuation created by the `await` statements were somehow causing a problem.  I don't really want to dig into the guts of the compiler-generated continuations if I don't have to, though.

Comment: It must be really magic, because that last code block isn't even valid C# and `await` statements do no cause problems.

Comment: I was just guessing about the continuations.  I didn't think the languageext library had anything in particular to do with the issue so I was casting about for any possible explanation.