# languageExt Either and type inferencing

Tags: c#, functional-programming, async-await

(Related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057927/languageext-either-map-bind-with-a-task-in-the-right-position))

I'm using the language-ext library in C# and trying to get `Tasks` returning `Either` values to compose properly and having a tough time with the type inferencing.  It just isn't working out the way I would expect.

There are three methods involved here:

- `Initialization`:  Returns a `Task<Either<Exception, ADUser>>`
- `createUserMapping`: Takes an `ADUser` and returns an `Either<Exception, UserMapping>`
- `AddUser`: takes an `UserMapping` and returns a `Task<Either<Exception, int>>`

I would like to return the results of `AddUser`.  It seems pretty simple.  Somehow the types are just not lining up, though.

What I have now is this:

```
return Initialization
    .Bind(eu => eu.Bind(createUserMapping).AsTask())
    .Bind(eu => eu.Bind(async u => await AddUser(u)));
```

However, while Intellisense is telling me that the `u` in the last async lambda is of type `UserMapping`, when it gets passed into the `AddUser` call I get the error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Exception' to 'UserMapping'
```

Why is the compiler getting confused as to the type of the parameter when it isn't confused about it at the start of the lambda?  Is there a better way of getting this to work?

I have tried variations using `BindT` as well as LINQ expressions.  I just can't seem to get this to work out.

Comment: What are the signatures of the `Bind` methods being used here?  Are all 4 the same method?  What is the type of `eu` in both lambas?  I would think that you would not want to await in the last lamba, and instead just return the `Task`.

Comment: @JamesFaix, the issue was in the version of the library I was using.  I was trying to avoid using a beta release but if I want it to work I had to move to 2.0.  The types were correct but the library just didn't cooperate at version 1.9.  At 2.0+ it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll post the solution from the [language-ext issue you raised](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/207), just in case anybody else gets stumped.

```
public Task<Either<Exception, int>> Issue207() =>
    Initialization
        .BindT(createUserMapping)
        .BindT(addUser);

static Task<Either<Exception, ADUser>> Initialization =>
    Right<Exception, ADUser>(ADUser.New("test user")).AsTask();

static Either<Exception, UserMapping> createUserMapping(ADUser user) =>
    Right<Exception, UserMapping>(UserMapping.New(user.ToString() + " mapped"));

static Task<Either<Exception, int>> addUser(UserMapping user) =>
    Right<Exception, int>(user.ToString().Length).AsTask();
```

The issue was one of using mismatched monadic types.  Version `1.x` was less tolerant of transformer types, and especially of returning the wrong transformer type in the delegate provided to `Bind`.  Version `2.x` now supports returning the inner monad or the outer monad for `BindT` (rather than just the inner monad on `1.x`) which allows the code to look a lot prettier.

On `v1` and `v2` the Bind function only accepts a return value (for the bind delegate provided) of `Either<L, R>` (for the `Either` monad) and `Task<A>` for the `Task` monad. This is the correct signature for Bind. In v1 and v2 there are also a load of code generated 'transformer' extension methods, that allow you to work with nested monads `M1<M2<A>>` (like `Task<Either<L, R>>`). These transformer functions all have a `T` suffix (like `BindT`). On version 1 `BindT` also had the signature for the delegate to return `Either<L, R>` or `Task<A>` (the inner monad of the transformer) whereas in `v2` there are two `BindT` extensions for every transformer type, one that returns the inner monad (as in `v1`), and one that allows for the outer monad to be returned (i.e. `Task<Either<L, R>>`). So my solution with `BindT` could only work with `v2`.

You could still achieve what you wanted in `v1`, it just wouldn't be as attractive as the `v2` solution. The issue with your original solution is that this `eu.Bind(async u => await AddUser(u))` is doing a `Bind` on the `Either` of `eu`, but the return type for `Bind` on `eu` should be an `Either<L, R>`. Whereas you're feeding it a `Task<Either<L, R>>`. So that's why you saw the errors you did.

As explained above, `BindT` in `v2` accepts the result type of the nested monads, and so that's why returning `Task<Either<L, R>>` 'just works' with `BindT`.

It's always important to 'follow the types' with functional programming (I find). They are the truth in a more more robust way than the OO world. And so if things aren't fitting together then they either need to be mapped into the correct types, or you've got a bug.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'returning the wrong transformer type'.  I have run into similar issues in 2.x, but they were easier to find a solution to.  I may have a more fundamental misunderstanding here if there was a mismatch somewhere.  I still don't see what was wrong.

Comment: On v1 the `Bind` function only accepted a return value (for the bind delegate provided) of `Either<L, R>` (for the `Either` monad) and `Task<A>` for the `Task` monad.  This is the correct signature for `Bind`.  In v1 there are also a load of code generated 'transformer' extension methods, that allow you to work with nested monads  `M1<M2<A>>`  (like `Task<Either<L, R>>`).  These transformer functions all have a `T` suffix (like `BindT`).  `BindT` also had the signature for the delegate to return `Either<L, R>` or `Task<A>` (the inner monad of the transformer)...

Comment: ... whereas in v2 there are two `BindT` extensions for every transformer type, one that returns the inner monad (as in v1), and one that allows for the outer monad to be returned (i.e. `Task<Either<L, R>>`).  So my solution with `BindT` could only work with v2.

Comment: You could still achieve what you wanted in v1, it just wouldn't be as attractive as the v2 solution.  The issue with your original solution is that this `eu.Bind(async u => await AddUser(u))` is doing a `Bind` on the `Either` of `eu`, but the return type for `Bind` on `eu` should be an `Either<L, R>`.  Whereas you're feeding it a `Task<Either<L, R>>`.  So that's why you saw the errors you did.

As explained above, `BindT` in v2 accepts the result type of the nested monads, and so that's why returning `Task<Either<L, R>>` 'just works' with `BindT`.

Comment: It's always important to 'follow the types' with functional programming (I find).  They are the truth in a more more robust way than the OO world.  And so if things aren't fitting together then they either need to be mapped into the correct types, or you've got a bug.

Comment: But just to make it entirely clear, there wasn't a bug or anything like that in language-ext.  Your code was wrong.  It's just the solution is much more attractive in v2 and you clearly would have benefited from moving to it :)

Comment: you lost me in that explanation.  I thought I *was* following the types.  I still don't understand why they didn't line up.  Are you saying that it would have worked if that `eu.Bind(...)` were `eu.Map(...)`, instead?

Comment: > Are you saying that it would have worked if that `eu.Bind(...)` were `eu.Map(...)`

No.  In your original post, you have four calls to `Bind`.  The outer ones that are fluently chained off `Initialization`, and the inner ones chained off `eu`.  

`Initialization` is a `Task<Either<Exception, ADUser>>`, which means that  calling `Bind` on it will give you a inner value (`eu`) of `Either<Exception, ADUser>`.  This is true for both of the ...

Comment: ...outer calls to `Bind` (well, they're both working on a `Task<Either<L, R>>`).  Then in the first `Bind` you call `eu.Bind(createUserMapping).AsTask()`, which will result in a `Task<Either<Exception, UserMapping>>`.  That is the correct expected result for the outer call to `Bind`, because it lines up with the `Initialization` type.   The problems comes in the second outer call of `Bind`.  The inner part of the `Bind` is working on `eu`, which is an `Either<Exception, UserMapping>`, ...

Comment: is the problem, then, that the second inner Bind is working on an `Either<Exception, UserMapping>` and returning a `Task<Either<Exception, UserMapping>>`?

Comment: ... so calling `Bind` on `eu` will expect a delegate of `Func<UserMapping, Either<Exception, R>>` where `R` is the expected right value (`int` in this case).  But the outer `Bind` doesn't expect a `Either<Exception, R>`, it expects a `Task<Either<Exception, R>>`.  So that is the first issue, that you're not returning a `Task`.

Comment: ... the second issue is that `addUser` returns a `Task<Either<Exception, int>>`, which is the expected result for the outer `Bind`, not the inner `Bind`, but you're returning it in the inner `Bind`.  If you changed the second inner `Bind` to `Map` then you'd see a result of `Either<Exception, Task<Either<Exception, int>>>`.  So you can see how `Bind` can't possibly work in this situation (neither can `Map`).  So you could have approached it a couple of ways:  1.  Don't return `Task<Either<Exception, int>>` from `addUser`,  make it synchronous and instead return `Either<Exception, int>>`......

Comment: ...then the second outer `Bind` could look like this:  `.Bind(eu => Task.Run(() => eu.Bind(u => AddUser(u))));`.  That allows the inner `Either` to do what it does best, but have the whole lot wrapped in an asyncrhonous `Task`.  Option 2. is to do what we've done, which is to use `BindT` which does all this heavy lifting for you.

Comment: OK. This is starting to make sense.  Thanks.  This area of working with Tasks can get pretty convoluted pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea why the `Bind` is behaving as it does but I did find a workable solution.  Instead of calling the `AddUser` directly I now have a new local method `addUser` that takes the `Either` and handles the request.  It looks like this:

```
    private async Task<Either<Exception, int>> addUser(Either<Exception, UserMapping> eu)
    {
        var nestedTask = eu.Map(u => uow.ControllerRepository.AddUser(u));

        var rv = nestedTask.Match(
            Right: t => identity(t),
            Left: e => Left<Exception, int>(e).AsTask());
        return await rv;
    }
```

Here, `nestedTask` is of type `Either<Exception, Task<Either<Exception, int>>>`.  So I take that apart in the `Match`, returning just the `Right` value or the `Left` (Exception) wrapped appropriately - as a `Task<Either<Exception, int>>`.

I also changed `createUserMapping` to take the `Either` instead of taking a `UserMapping`.

Now my top-level sequence of transformations looks like:

```
    public async Task<Either<Exception, int>> AddUser(ADUser user)
    {
        return await Initialization
            .Bind(eadu => createUserMapping(eadu).AsTask())  // eadu: Either<Exception, ADUser>
            .Bind(eum => addUser(eum));                      // eum:  Either<Exception, UserMapping>
    }
```

I don't know why my original attempts didn't work but at least I have a working solution for now.

If anyone can shed some light on the problem I was facing I would still like to hear about it.

=== Edit 4/5/17 ===

OK.  The issue was that I was using an old version of the library (pre 2.0).  When I upgraded the library to the latest beta (I was hoping to avoid a beta) I no longer have the problem.